# How does NodeJs handle microtasks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm currently learning about the event loop and tasks inside it. I've noticed that different asynchronous functions have different levels of priority, i.e `process.nextTick()` usually gets run before a `Promise` in the queue. Maybe I'm getting things wrong (if so please correct me), but I've been trying to search on the topic with no results. How does the event loop handle microtasks? Do each of them have a different priority?

Comment: @CristianTraìna All queues are working in FIFO order, and all promise microtasks are asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi `process.nextTick()` does not queue a microtask. It's not even part of the event loop. It gets handled in a separate queue called the "next tick queue" after every current operation is complete regardless of the event loop phase before continuing on to handle remaining microtasks and tasks from the event loop.